# Timescaledb: retention policy isn't removing data from hypertable

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

(note: I've also posted this as a github issue https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3653)

I have a hypertable `request_logs` configured with a 24 hour retention policy. The retention policy is being marked as running successfully, however no old data from the table is being removed. The table continues to grow day by day.

I checked and don't see any errors in the postgresql log files.

Could use additional guidance on where to look for information to troubleshoot this issue.

`request_logs` table structure

```
  \d+ request_logs;
  Table "public.request_logs"
Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
time      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              | 
referer   | bigint                   |           |          |         | plain   |              | 
useragent | bigint                   |           |          |         | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
"request_logs_time_idx" btree ("time" DESC)
Triggers:
ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON request_logs FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Child tables: _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_37_chunk,
_timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_38_chunk,
_timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_40_chunk
Access method: heap
```

This is the hypertable description retrieved by running `select * from _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable;`

```
 id | schema_name |  table_name  | associated_schema_name | associated_table_prefix | num_dimensions | chunk_sizing_func_schema |  chunk_sizing_func_name  | chunk_target_size | compression_state | compressed_hypertable_id | replication_factor 
----+-------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------
  1 | public      | request_logs | _timescaledb_internal  | _hyper_1                |              1 | _timescaledb_internal    | calculate_chunk_interval |                 0 |                 0 |                          |                   
(1 row)
```

This is the retention_policy retrieved by running `SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.job_stats;`.

```
 hypertable_schema | hypertable_name | job_id |      last_run_started_at      |    last_successful_finish     | last_run_status | job_status | last_run_duration |          next_start           | total_runs | total_successes | total_failures 
-------------------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------
 public            | request_logs    |   1002 | 2021-10-05 23:59:01.601404+00 | 2021-10-05 23:59:01.638441+00 | Success         | Scheduled  | 00:00:00.037037   | 2021-10-06 23:59:01.638441+00 |          8 |               8 |              0
                   |                 |      1 | 2021-10-05 08:38:20.473945+00 | 2021-10-05 08:38:21.153468+00 | Success         | Scheduled  | 00:00:00.679523   | 2021-10-06 08:38:21.153468+00 |         45 |              45 |              0
(2 rows)
```

**Relevant system information:**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- PostgreSQL version (output of `postgres --version`): 12
- TimescaleDB version (output of `\dx` in `psql`): 2.4.1
- Installation method: apt install process described https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/install-timescaledb/self-hosted/ubuntu/installation-apt-ubuntu/#installation-apt-ubuntu

Comment: Have you checked the chunk time interval?

The retention policy is chunk-based. So, if your chunk has data of 7 days it will delete the data only when the 7 days are out because it drops the entire chunk.

https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/set_chunk_time_interval/

Comment: @jonatasdp its set for 24 hours. Been over a week since I added the policy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though this might be related to a bug that has been fixed in version 2.4.2 of TimescaleDB. The GitHub report has been updated, if you find that the issue remains after upgrade, please update the issue on GitHub with your example. Thanks for reporting!
*Transparency: I work for Timescale*